# Is this Global singleton NavController (NavHostController) appropriate?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to access NavHostController created using rememberNavController, everywhere. So I created this Singleton object which stores the NavHostController.

Note

- I already know the advantages and disadvantages of singleton, so please don't bring that topic

Singleton object

```
object NavControllerDelegate {
    var navController: NavHostController? = null
}
```

```
setContent {
  val navController = rememberNavController()

  // Set singleton
  NavControllerDelegate.navController = navController
}
```

Now I can use this NavControllerDelegate.navController anywhere, in Compose functions or ViewModels.

But I have a problem, Android is warning me with the following warning text,

"Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to NavHostController which has field context pointing to Context); this is a memory leak"

My doubt is, how does this approach cause memory leak?

BTW, I don't want alternate options, just issues with this approach and what modifications should I make, to make it safe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can never make that safe, as per the warning. You might consider using tools like [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/), which will clearly show when a leak is occurring.

Comment: Thanks, I will learn and check LeakCanary and come back